# 502 Bad Gateway when deploying Flask app on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a pyFlask app using AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EC2).

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@rodkey/deploying-a-flask-application-on-aws-a72daba6bb80, and everything seemed to work okay, except now when I try to load the URL for my app I get a 502 bad gateway error: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inteh.png).

I have used this to run my app in the main app.py file:
`if __name__ == "__main__": app.run(debug=True)`

Following advice online, I have tried to have host=5000 and port=80 inside the app.run() but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea of what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Did you download and check logs from Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

In your Flask app, host should be `127.0.0.1` (or just leave it blank) and port should be `5000`. See the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html). You should be able to run the Flask app locally and view it at `http://127.0.0.1:5000` before deploying it to Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've already deployed my app and tested it locally with `http://127.0.0.1:5000`. My issue is that it will not load after following the instructions in the link you have attached, and the one I attached in my original question. It works locally but I am struggling to get it working on EC.

Comment: Then you need to check the server logs to make sure it is actually running without errors on Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

Your tutorial that you followed is from **2015**. Since then, EB has seen many, many changes and the tutorial is simply obsolete. Please find some new tutorials.

Good start will be AWS docs:

- [Deploying a flask application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html)